# findViewById(R.id.bAdd) error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn android app development and I am very much at the beginning.
Can some one please tell me what am I doing wrong here?
In my MainActivity.java I get errors on add, sub and display (bAdd/bSubb/display cannot be resolved or is not field)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is 0" 
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"/>

    <Button
        android:layout-width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Add one"
        android:text="Add one"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bAdd" />

    <Button
        android:layout-width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Add one"
        android:text="Subtract one"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bSub" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you show `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: check whether your R.java is present or not. If it not then try to build your project and if also does not work then try to close and then reopen eclipse.

Comment: save every file and then check it.

Comment: In main activity_main.xml there is error on button - No resource identifier found for attribute layout-width in package android.

Comment: You've used a minus sign '-' instead of an underscore '_' in layout_width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
 <Button
android:layout-width="250dp"
```

to

```
<Button
android:layout_width="250dp" // _
```

Same for the textview and buttons.

If you have errors in your resource files R. java will not be generated leading to errors

Answer (score 1):

save you xml and recheck :)
it will be solved for sure if u have given the same id names.

Comment: i tried several things that ppl had mentioned on this tutorial from youtube.. like saving , exit ADT and opening it again !! none solve it

Comment: some time captal letters in id names in xml create problem. so change bSub to b_sub and others too similarly in both xml and java file.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Button
    android:layout-width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Add one"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd" />

<Button
    android:layout-width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Add one"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/bSub" />
```

There is a **-** in the `layout_width` attribute.

Secondly, i would like to bring your attention to the `onClick` attribute.You have defined onClick function by the name : - **Add one**.

You cannot have a space in a function name.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, to resolve this please do below :

a) Save the activity_main.xml file.
b) If you are still facing the issue, just delete R.java file in "gen" directory.

Comment: This question has already an answer that solves the exact issue OP had. See @Raghunandan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figured it out.  Change tvDisplay to whatever you named it on the xml file.

Mine worked when I did this:
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);